# error: XML document must have a top level element

Tags: xml

I use an XML file in a program I have developed.

When I install the program on another machine I get the following error:

```
"XML document must have a top level element".
```

Is there a problem in my XML content?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<RefData version="1.0" exporter="EA.25">
    <DataSet name="RTF Document Templates" table="t_document where DocType='SSDOCSTYLE'" filter="DocID='#DocID#'">
        <DataRow>
            <Column name="DocID" value="{F9CAEC01-4CB8-433e-8881-9F9BF57720E2}"/>
            <Column name="DocName" value="MyXMLFileName"/>
            <Column name="Style" value="Zip=1;"/>
            <Column name="ElementID" value="SSDOCSTYLE"/>
            <Column name="ElementType" value="SSDOCSTYLE"/>
            <Column name="BinContent" xmlns:dt="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes" dt:dt="bin.base64">UEsDBBQAAAAIAGp9LkR/OD678CQAADBeAQAHABEAc3RyLmRhdFVUDQAHKVvVUilb1VIpW9VS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</Column>
            <Column name="DocType" value="SSDOCSTYLE"/>
            <Column name="IsActive" value="1"/>
        </DataRow>
    </DataSet>
</RefData>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the spaces before the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>` are in the XML file rather than being a formatting buglet, that is your problem: the first character in the file must be '<'

Comment: No, There are no spaces before that line. It is looks like only in current post

Comment: It is possible there are illegal non-printing characters at the end of the file (maybe a null?) The only legal whitespace characters that may follow the root element are 0x20, 0x09, 0x0D & 0x0A. It depends how picky your parser is, to some extent

Comment: No characters after the last closing tag. What I have to do?

Comment: Try looking at the file after installation on the other machine, using a hex editor/viewer. It is possible the file is being changed in some way by the installation process. Look for strange characters, such as a null or a ^Z. Anything before the first '<' is illegal, and anything except one of the valid whitespace characters after the closing '>' is illegal (unless it forms part of a well-formed comment or PI)

Comment: I appreciate your detailed comment. There is no illegal characters.Everything is definitely like the code in my post.

Comment: Then, there is _definitely_ no problem at all with your XML file and it is _impossible_ that this error occured while processing the XML you have shown.

Comment: @Max, you are right. Re-installation retrieves the following result: each < character is now >, and so is the opposite. Any idea why and how? Thanx

Comment: Did you install after dark? Must have been the Gremlins! ;-)

Comment: @Max, LOL! but have you a solution?

Comment: It sounds like the installer is making a mess of things. You could try changing to a different installer, or maybe modifying your program to expect a zipped XML file, and zipping it before letting the installer touch it.

Comment: @Max, I have created already some installers and the error is still appears. Didn't understand properly the zip file issue- what is the deal?

Comment: My idea is that if the installer is looking inside the file and changing characters, if you hide the XML by giving the installer a zip file instead, it won't be able to do this. Then your program will be able to unzip the file and read the (hopefully untouched) XML.

Comment: @Max, Great idea! Can you please guide me a little more how to do such a thing and unzipped via code? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Max, not sure now that XML was damaged during installation. I check if the XML starts with "?" (The upside-down first first-line character) and result is not! What in the world causes the error if not the XML issue?

Answer (score 2):

The XML file you have shown starts with:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
```

As you can see, there are whitespace characters in front of the XML declaration. Is it not allowed to have *any* characters before this line. Remove the whitespace and try again.

I quote from [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20140228005715/http://xmlwriter.net/xml_guide/xml_declaration.shtml):

> If the XML declaration is included, it must be situated at the first
> position of the first line in the XML document

If this is a typo in your post only, the problem lies elsewhere. When I remove the trailing whitespace, your XML displays without warning in a browser.

---

**EDIT**: The error:

```
"XML document must have a top level element".
```

Means that your XML file does not have one single root element (also called document node) which encloses all other elements. But this is definitely not the case with the XML you have shown.

**A bad example** (that causes this error):

```
<foo>
  <bar/>
  <bar/>
</foo>
<bar/>
```

**A well-formed example**

```
<foo>
  <bar>
  <bar>
</foo>
```

Comment: First of all thanks. No, There are no spaces before that line.

Comment: I assume you meant to say that there are no whitespaces _in front_ of the declaration on the same line? In this case, it is not your XML file which is at fault.

Comment: That's why I asked if the XML content is problematic.

Comment: No it is not. At least not the one you have shown. To avoid encoding issues, you could copy the content of your XML file to a neutral editor like Notepad and save it again, choosing the correct encoding.

Comment: If you do not know which encoding to select, you should encode it as "utf-8".

Comment: Not going to submit an edit while the moderation strike is on, but the link in this post (http://xmlwriter.net/xml_guide/xml_declaration.shtml) currently redirects to https://xmlwriter.net/goodbye.html - which just says [SLATFATF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/So_Long,_and_Thanks_for_All_the_Fish). Working archive link to use instead: https://web.archive.org/web/20140228005715/http://xmlwriter.net/xml_guide/xml_declaration.shtml